# NativeScript Angular: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'addpatient'

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, nativescript

So I just want my fab button in my home.component.ts to route to my addpatient.component. using tabs scaffolding, and placed my addpatient folder inside of the home folder. this is what my directory looks like:

[app directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlV6Y.png)
[rest of app directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oEeB.png)

I'm really new to this so I feel like I'm just missing something really simple

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, NgModule } from 
"@angular/core";
var Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
import { Fab } from "nativescript-floatingactionbutton";

import { AddPatientComponent } from "./addpatient/addpatient.component";

import { Router } from "@angular/router";
registerElement("Fab", () => Fab);


@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router){}

    public redirectAddPatient(){
        this.router.navigate(["addpatient]);
    }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<FAB row="1" (tap)="redirectAddPatient()" icon="res://ic_plus_white" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" class="fab-button"></FAB>
```

**addpatient.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Patient } from "./../../objects/patient.module"
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "addpatient",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./addpatient.component.html"
})

export class AddPatientComponent {
    public lastname: string;

    ngOnInit(): void{
        let patient = new Patient();

        patient.setLastName(this.lastname);
        console.log("lastname: ", patient.getLastName());
    }
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { AddPatientComponent } from 
"./tabs/home/addpatient/addpatient.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./tabs/home/home.component";

export const appRoutes: any = [
    {path: "", component: HomeComponent},
    {path: "addpatient", component: AddPatientComponent}
];

export const appComponents: any = [
    HomeComponent,
    AddPatientComponent
];
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";

import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { appComponents, appRoutes } from "./app.routing";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, ...appComponents],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
})

class AppComponentModule {

}

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a quote missing in `redirectAddPatient()` of your HomeComponent: `this.router.navigate(["addpatient*here*]);`
Second, the module you're bootstrapping is the AppModule, not AppComponentModule. I'd recommend adding the declarations and imports of the AppComponentModule to your AppModule and removing the AppComponentModule completely since it has no purpose (as far as I can tell).